# Fit an ellipse with constraints

Tags: conic-sections, constraints

I'd like to fit an ellipse with the equation of

$ x^2 + ay^2 + bx + c =0 $

This is basically the equation of an ellipse with no tilt and with its center on the horizontal axis.

I have some examples of how to fix curve on the general for of an ellipse, but I do not know how to apply the mentioned constraints. Can anyone kindly guid me on this or refer me to a page or document?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the constraints

Comment: the constraints are that there is no tilt (no $xy$ parameter) and also the center of the ellipse is on the horizontal axis namely $x$ axis (no $y$ parameter). Now how can I define the constraint matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some $(x,y)$ points (at least $3$) and you want an exact fit, you have to solve the system of equations in three unknowns $a$, $b$, $c$ that you get by plugging in these values for $x$ and $y$.  If you have more points than equations and the fit is not necessarily exact, you might do linear least squares.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using the least square method most of the time results in a conic that is not ellipse. For this we need to define the constraint of $4ac-b^2>0$ for the general form of conic ($ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$). But in my case $a=1;b=e=0$. So how I can define the constraint matrix in this case please?

Comment: Your equation $x^2 + a y^2 + b x + c = 0$ defines an ellipse if $a > 0$ and $b^2 > 4 c$.  If least squares doesn't produce a solution satisfying these, there is such a thing as "constrained least squares" (e.g. Maple's LSSolve can incorporate constraints).

Comment: I know that there are packages that can do this. But I need to have the code and also the logic behind it in order to implement it myself. Any idea on how I can do this without any specific package or toolbox and just by simple programming?

Answer (score 0):

I may be totally wrong; so forgive me if this is the case.

I have the feeling that you want to use a general software for fitting conics and that you want to restrict it to your case (from here comes your constraint).

As Robert Israel answered, why don't you just use the basic definition of the least square fit and minimize with respect to parameters $a,b,c$ the objective function $$\Phi=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 + ay_i^2 + bx_i + c)^2$$ Writing the partials and setting them to zero leads to a simple set of three linear equations in $a,b,c$.

**Added later**

As said in comments, I used your data points and the problem solves nicely.

If you want to force your sofware to generate an ellipse, I give you a trick : you have $N$ data points of coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$. So, add to your data set $N$ extra points with coordinates $$x_{N+i}=x_i$$  $$y_{N+i}=-y_i$$ I bet that the difficulties you face are related to the fact that all the $y$'s you gave me are positive.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that, using this method, most of the the solution does not form an ellipse. For this we need to define the constraint of $4ac−b2>0$ for the general conic equation of  (ax2+bxy+cy2+dx+ey+f=0). But in my case a=1;b=e=0. So how I can define the constraint matrix in this case please?

Comment: Give me a few points.

Comment: here you are: http://pastebin.com/y00UHdQJ

Comment: Using your data, an immediate calculation gave $a=0.3173733831$, $b=-10.73738924$, $c=-80173.94167$.

Comment: It may works for several data points, but this is not the point. The correct way of doing this is to consider the constraint of  4ac−b2>0 for the general conic equation of (ax2+bxy+cy2+dx+ey+f=0) as stated everywhere in literature. I appreciate, if you can, answer the question which is how I should change the constraint matrix to math my constraints as well?